# How to write functions to be called from within a @tornado.testing.gen_test?

Tags: python, tornado

So I've got some code I want to test, and I'm encountering what looks like a pretty horrible side effect of the yield generator-based nature of `@tornado.testing.gen_test`'s expected input tests:

```
class GameTest(tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    def new_game(self):
        ws = yield websocket_connect('address')
        ws.write_message('new_game')
        response = yield ws.read_message()
        # I want to say:
        # return response

    @tornado.testing.gen_test
    def test_new_game(self):
        response = self.new_game()
        # do some testing
```

The problem is that I can't return a value from a generator, so my natural instinct here is wrong. Furthermore, I can't do this:

```
class GameTest(tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    def new_game(self):
        ws = yield websocket_connect('address')
        ws.write_message('new_game')
        response = yield ws.read_message()
        yield response, True

    @tornado.testing.gen_test
    def test_new_game(self):
        for i in self.new_game():
            if isinstance(i, tuple):
                response, success = i
                break
        # do some testing
```

Because then I encounter the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write_message'
```

Obviously, I can include the entire test generation code in the test, but that's really ugly, hard to maintain, etc. Does this testing pattern really make indirection so difficult?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `@gen.coroutine` on asynchronous functions to be called by `@gen_test` methods, just like in non-test code.  `@gen_test` is an adapter for your top-level test function that makes it possible to use asynchronous code in the synchronous unittest interface.

```
@gen.coroutine
def new_game(self):
    ws = yield websocket_connect('address')
    ws.write_message('new_game')
    response = yield ws.read_message()
    raise gen.Return(response)

@tornado.testing.gen_test
def test_new_game(self):
    response = yield self.new_game()
    # do some testing
```

In Python 3.3+, you can use `return response` instead of `raise gen.Return(response)`.  You can even omit the `@gen.coroutine` if you use `yield from` at the call site.